# XPath expression not working on a website

Tags: python, scrapy

I am crawling a website

this is my path

```
    response.xpath(".//div[@id='search_listing']/ul[@id='listings']/li[@class='item']")
```

i got empty result, though as you see bellow ,there are values:

[image]

I am suing scrapy

Comment: Works for me in the scrapy shell..getting non-empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the extra space after the `item` class:

```
<li class="item ">...
           HERE^
```

This is the reason why your `@class='item'` condition is not working. You would have to use [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) for a partial match:

```
.//div[@id='search_listing']/ul[@id='listings']/li[contains(@class, 'item')]
```

---

I would though look into CSS selectors for a more concise location technique:

```
response.css("#search_listing #listings .item")
```

Comment: i tried your code `container = response.xpath(".//div[@id='search_listing']/ul[@id='listings']/li[contains(@class='item')]")` but i get error , is it correct please ?

Comment: the error is: `Invalid XPath: .//div[@id='search_listing']/ul[@id='listings']/li[contains(@class='item')]`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli note how you are using `contains()` - should be comma instead of `=` as in the answer..